# How to swap values in PyTorch tensor without using in-place operation (conserve gradient)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor called `state` of shape `torch.Size([N, 2**n, 2**n])`, and I want to apply the following operations:

```
state[[0,1]] = state[[1,0]]
state[0] = -1*state[0]
```

Both of these are in-place operations. Are there some out-of-place operations that I can substitute them with? These lines are **inside a for-loop**, so it would be a bit difficult to just create new variables.

Comment: Why is it difficult to create new variables? Memory cost? PyTorch may have to create them internally to track your gradients. Your forward behavior looks rather simple. You may want to consider bypassing autograd and computing the gradient manually instead (just an idea without knowing your entire loop, though).

Comment: Yes, you are correct that pytorch will create new variable anyways. My goal was keeping everything in the variable 'state', without creating new variables. I think I figured it out (see answer below). I am not yet 100% sure if this is the correct/most efficient way of doing it, but I do hope so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out!

**Replace:**

```
state[[0,1]] = state[[1,0]] # in-place operation
```

**with:**

```
state = state[[1,0]] # out-of-place operation
```

And for the second line, we **replace:**

```
state[0] = -1*state[0] # in-place operation
```

**with:**

```
# out-of-place operations
temp = torch.ones(state.shape).type(state.type()).to(state.device)
temp[1] = -1*temp[1]
state = state*temp
```

This seems to be doing the job!